# MySQL function for login, return 1 or 0

Tags: mysql

i'm trying to make a login function on a website that is connected to a mySQL server. I have problems making the function work however.

```
CREATE FUNCTION login_function
(IN nick varchar(10),
IN pw varchar(10))
RETURNS NUMBER(1)
DETERMINIS
BEGIN

DECLARE v_result NUMBER(1);
SET v_result=0;

SELECT COUNT(username)
INTO v_result
FROM login
WHERE username=nick
AND password=pw;
RETURN v_result;
END;
##
```

Message:
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
    'IN nick varchar(10),
    IN pw varchar(10))
    RETURNS NUMBER(1)
    DETERMINIS
    BEGIN'
at line 2.

What the database looks like:
https://gyazo.com/6ea3983e30bd564cd6f42ee58a327d5b

Comment: *"You have an error in your SQL syntax"*

Comment: You've not changed the delimiter before declaring the function. BTW - storing cleartext passwords is not a good idea.

Comment: Are you sure that the above query is causing the problem? Seems like `DETERMINIS` does not appear above, neither does `IN pw varchar(10)`

Comment: @cwallenpoole Fixed, did not help :(

Comment: Updated the post a bit, with some syntax mistake and also edited the error-message a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For functions you [do not need to provide the direction of a parameter](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) because all parameters must be `in` parameters. So, the definition of the function correctly:

```
CREATE FUNCTION login_function
(nick varchar(10),
 pw varchar(10))
...
```

You also do not need the semicolon after the last `end`, and `DETERMINIS` should be `DETERMINISTIC`, and `number(1)` should be `tinyint` or `bool`.

Comment: Removed in and changed the delimeter to "##"

Comment: There are quite a few other issues with the code. The removal of the `in` just rids you of the particular syntax error you mentioned in your code.

Comment: Yeah, it worked fine when I changed to tinyint as well.

Comment: Well, now that I made the function and try to call it by:
EXECUTE login_function(admin, admin);

I get syntax-error?

Comment: 'admin', 'admin' -> you want to pass strings

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems. First, you shouldn't include the `IN` keyword for parameters. Parameters are implied to be `IN` anyway.

Your next problem is that MySQL is reading your `;` and thinking "I have reached the end of the statement". So it is trying to parse only part of your function before returning. You need to set your delimeter to something else so that it knows "process this entire block". Here's what happens when I try both in the console:

```
mysql> create function foo (IN i int, IN j int) returns int BEGIN 
    -> declare q int;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN i int, IN j int) returns int BEGIN
declare q int' at line 1
mysql> create function foo (i int, j int) returns int BEGIN declare q int;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
mysql> create function foo (IN i int, IN j int) returns int  begin return i*j; end //
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN i int, IN j int) returns int  begin return j; end' at line 1
mysql> DELIMITER //
mysql> create function foo (i int, j int) returns int
    -> BEGIN 
    -> declare q int;
    -> SET q = i*j;
    -> return q;
    -> end;
    -> //
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
```

You also have a data type of `NUMBER`. This should be one of the integer varieties (`tinyint`, or `int(1)`, for example) or boolean.

Finally, you've inserted some sort of keyword `DETERMINIS` into your function creation. I've not seen that in any MySQL documentation before. (As shadow pointed out, it should be `DETERMINISTIC`… I admit that I missed that).

Comment: Changed the delimeter to "##". Also removed the "IN"
Now I get:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NUMBER(1) DETERMINIS BEGIN DECLARE v_result NUMBER(1); SET v_result=0; SELECT ' at line 4

Comment: @Jeppezon What is the keyword `DETERMINIS`?

Comment: @cwallenpoole it should be `deterministic`, as I pointed out in my answer :)

Comment: @Shadow Yea… got that. I was stuck on "Is that Dutch or something? Could he be trying to translate a keyword and failing? What keyword would he be trying to translate?"

Comment: On a side note: `DETERMINIS` _is_ a word… in Esperanto.

Comment: First I thought it was latin :)

Comment: I asked Google. It said Esperanto. :-)